# с++ задача про черепаху

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Помогите решить
Вывести маршрут максимальной стоимости
В левом верхнем углу прямоугольной таблицы размером N×M находится черепашка. В каждой клетке таблицы записано некоторое число. Черепашка может перемещаться вправо или вниз, при этом маршрут черепашки заканчивается в правом нижнем углу таблицы.

Подсчитаем сумму чисел, записанных в клетках, через которую проползла черепашка (включая начальную и конечную клетку). Найдите наибольшее возможное значение этой суммы и маршрут, на котором достигается эта сумма.

Входные данные

В первой строке входных данных записаны два натуральных числа N и M, не превосходящих 100 — размеры таблицы. Далее идут N строк, каждая из которых содержит M чисел, разделенных пробелами — описание таблицы. Все числа в клетках таблицы целые и могут принимать значения от 0 до 100.

Выходные данные

Первая строка выходных данных содержит максимальную возможную сумму, вторая — маршрут, на котором достигается эта сумма. Маршрут выводится в виде последовательности, которая должна содержать N−1 букву D, означающую передвижение вниз и M−1 букву R, означающую передвижение направо. Если таких последовательностей несколько, необходимо вывести ровно одну (любую) из них.
Мое решение вот. Но вывод не знаю как правильно организовать. У меня не так как нужно

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
 
#define int long long int
 
int gcd(int a, int b) { return __gcd(a, b); }
 
int lcm(int a, int b) { return abs(a * b) / gcd(a, b); }
 
int32_t main() {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(0);
  cout.tie(0);
  cout.precision(9);
  cout << fixed;
 
  int n;
  int m;
  cin >> n >> m;
 
  vector<vector<int>> a(n, vector<int>(m));
  for (auto& i : a) {
    for (auto& j : i) {
      char c;
      cin >> c;
 
      j = c - '0';
    }
  }
 
  vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int>(m));
 
  dp[0][0] = a[0][0];
 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        continue;
 
      if (i == 0) {
        dp[i][j] = a[i][j] + dp[i][j - 1];
      } else if (j == 0) {
        dp[i][j] = a[i][j] + dp[i - 1][j];
      } else {
        dp[i][j] = a[i][j] + max(dp[i][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j]);
      }
    }
  }
 
  vector<vector<char>> ans(n, vector<char>(m, '-'));
 
  vector<int> dx = {0, -1};
  vector<int> dy = {-1, 0};
 
  int x = n - 1;
  int y = n - 1;
 
  ans[x][y] = '#';
 
  while (x != 0 || y != 0) {
    int max_one = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int max_i = 0;
    int max_j = 0;
 
    for (size_t d = 0; d < dx.size(); ++d) {
      int i = x + dx[d];
      int j = y + dy[d];
 
      bool ok = i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < n && j < n;
 
      if (ok && max_one < dp[i][j]) {
        max_one = dp[i][j];
        max_i = i;
        max_j = j;
      }
    }
 
    ans[max_i][max_j] = '#';
 
    x = max_i;
    y = max_j;
  }
 
  cout << dp[n - 1][m - 1] << '\n';
 
  ans[0][0] = '#';
 
  for (const auto& i : ans) {
    copy(i.cbegin(), i.cend(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ""));
 
    cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Выложите попытки решить задачу, даже если они неудачные, мы поможем до вести их до финала. А без них ваш вопрос просто закроют.

Comment: Я с выводом чет как-то не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Вот в том месте, где заполняете ячейку `dp[][]`, записывайте направление в дополнительную матрицу такого же размера.

Вместо `max(dp[i][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j]);` используйте свой выбор максимума, чтобы знать направление прихода в ячейку.

По окончанию заполнения таблиц размотайте путь из последней ячейки в обратном направлении

*(а если начать решение ДП из последней ячейки, то путь из первой сразу в нужном направлении получится)*